# If $G$ is a finite group of automorphisms of $L/k$, then $\hom_k(L^G,k_s)=\hom_k(L,k_s)/G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, automorphism-group

Let $L/k$ be a finite separable extension and let $G$ be a finite group of automorphisms. We also fix a separable closure $k_s$ of $k$.

I want to prove that $\hom_k(L^G,k_s)=\hom_k(L,k_s)/G$, where two elements $\varphi,\psi\in\hom_k(L,k_s)$ are identified if $\varphi=\psi\circ g$ for some $g\in G$. In other words, I want to prove that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ agree on $L^G$ if and only if $\varphi=\psi\circ g$ for some $g\in G$.

This seems closely related to Galois theory but the only result I know in that could be useful is that $L/L^G$ is Galois and its Galois group is $G$ but I don't see how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. For "only if". If $\phi$ and $\psi$ agree on $L^G$ then, considering them as $k$-automorphisms of $L$, $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$ is in the Galois group of $L|L^G$.

For "if". Check directly if $\psi$ and $\psi \circ g$ agree on $L^G$.

Comment: Surely $\psi$ and $\psi\circ g$ agree on $L^G$. But what do you mean by saying that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ "are" in the Galois group? They surely aren't automorphisms of $L$.

Comment: Since $L$ is separable, up to isomorphism you may assume that $k_s$ contains $L$, and so, since $L|L^G$ is Galois, $\phi (L)\subset L$.

Comment: I understand that $\varphi$ defines a morphism $L\to L$. But why is it an automorphism? And how does that solves our problem?

Comment: Sorry, I mean $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$ is in the Galois group of $L|L^G$, and you then define $g$ as this element.

Comment: In order to $\varphi\circ\psi^{-1}$ to make sense we have to prove anyway that $\psi:L\to L$ is an automorphism, dont we?

Comment: $\psi$ and $\varphi$ are injective obviously, and $k$-linear maps between vector spaces of the same finite dimension over $k$, so they are isomorphisms.